Xero credential refresh happening in postman background but not via requests
I have a question, what are the headers it passes in the postman background when i click refresh for exprired Oauth bearer token? I need to replicate that to a Python request function
This function is not working regarding Xero
import requests

token_endpoint = "https://identity.xero.com/connect/token"
client_id = "YourClientID"
refresh_token = "YourRefreshToken"

payload = {
    "grant_type": "refresh_token",
    "client_id": client_id,
    "refresh_token": refresh_token
}

response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=payload)

if response.status_code == 200:
    token_data = response.json()
    new_access_token = token_data.get("access_token")
    new_refresh_token = token_data.get("refresh_token")
    print("Access token refreshed successfully:", new_access_token)
    print("New refresh token:", new_refresh_token)
else:
    print("Failed to refresh access token. Status code:",response.status_code)`

Could someone help?
It returns 400 Bad Request,
I need status 200, Link for docs: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/pkce-flow/#refreshing-access-and-refresh-tokens

The header should be Content-Type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
url = 'https://identity.xero.com/connect/token'
        
headers={
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
        
payload={
   'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
   'client_id' : client_id,
   'refresh_token' : refresh_token
}
     
        
r = requests.post(url,headers=headers,json=payload)

